# I need two things to happen with one link

Tags: html, hyperlink, google-ads-api

i have a link in place, which opens a popup window that gives you instructions on how to add this page to your bookmarks. Now i also want the link to fire a conversion in adwords when it gets clicked. For that i have a script from google which i tried ti combine with the existing link, but i think i did something wrong since no conversion gets fired in my test. Please help me here:

```html
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" onClick="goog_report_conversion" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark this page!</a>
 
 
 
<!-- Google Code for People who added website to their bookmarks Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
 goog_snippet_vars = function() {
   var w = window;
   w.google_conversion_id = XXXXXXXX;
   w.google_conversion_label = "COldCKSHnl8Q2cu9ywM";
   w.google_remarketing_only = false;
 }
 // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
 goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
   goog_snippet_vars();
   window.google_conversion_format = "3";
   window.google_is_call = true;
   var opt = new Object();
   opt.onload_callback = function() {
   if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
     window.location = url;
   }
 }
 var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
 if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
   conv_handler(opt);
 }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
 
 
 
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
            // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
            if ('sidebar' in window && 'addPanel' in window.sidebar) {
               window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
            } else if( /*@cc_on!@*/false) { // IE Favorite
                window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title);
            } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
                alert('Please press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D in order to add this page to your bookmarks, you can also use your browsers bookmark menu to do that.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
Setting up an onclick handler for conversions
First, make sure you selected Click instead of Page load from the "Tracking event" section of the "Advanced tag settings" in Part I of the instructions above. Your conversion tag should look like something this:

  <!-- Google Code for Add to Cart Conversion Page
  In your html page, add the snippet and call goog_report_conversion
  when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    goog_snippet_vars = function() {
      var w = window;
      w.google_conversion_id = 12345678;
      w.google_conversion_label = "abcDeFGHIJklmN0PQ";
      w.google_conversion_value = 13.00;
      w.google_conversion_currency = "USD";
      w.google_remarketing_only = false;
    }
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
    goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
      goog_snippet_vars();
      window.google_conversion_format = "3";
      var opt = new Object();
      opt.onload_callback = function() {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
    }
    var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
    if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
      conv_handler(opt);
    }
  }
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
  </script>
 
Now that you (or the person in charge of your website) have the conversion tracking tag, you're ready to paste. Here's how:

Go to the page on your website that shows the clickable button or link. Then open up the HTML code so you can edit it.
Find the body tags (<body></body>) of the page, then paste the code snippet you generated in AdWords between those two tags.
Adjust the HTML code to add the onclick handler. The particular onclick command you use will depend on how the link or button is displayed on your site: text link, image, or button.
Here's some sample code close up:

HTML before conversion tracking code (Sample only. Don't use in your website's code.)

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Sample HTML File</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 This is the body of your web page.
 </body>
 </html>
 
Use the following command if the link is shown as:

 

a text link

 <body>
 <!-- Below is a sample link for a file download.
 You need to replace the URL for the file and the
 DOWNLOAD NOW text with the text you want to hyperlink. -->
 <a onclick="goog_report_conversion
  ('http://www.example.com/whitepapers/a.pdf')"
  href="#" >DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
 </body>
 </html>
 
an image

 <!-- Below is a sample image for a file download.
 Replace download_button.gif with your
 button image and the document URL with your file's URL. -->
 <body>
 <img src="download_button.gif" alt="Download Whitepaper"
  width="32" height="32"
  onClick="goog_report_conversion
  ('http://www..pdf')"/>
 </body>
 </html>
 
For the tracking to work, you'll need to make sure you include both the tag and the appropriate onclick tags from one of the examples above. This tells AdWords to record a conversion only when a customer clicks on a chosen link or button.
```

Comment: The second code snipped are the instructions from google adwords.

Comment: Have you tried adding `google_report_conversion()` to the start of the onclick method you set using jquery? Remove it it from the link markup and put it in the method then see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it works the following way:

```html
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion
  ('')" id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar"  title="bookmark this page">Bookmark this page!</a>
```